# Push universal publish artifact via Azure CLI (az artifacts universal publish)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-artifacts

I am using this command:

```
az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/project/ --project="myProject" --scope project --feed myFeed --name someName --version 0.0.2 --description "some files" --path .
```

To upload another package to the feed.
The issue is that I need to update the version every time. is there a way for the command to update it automatically in the next patch?

I know it is possible via the pipeline :

```
versionOption: 'patch'
```

Will be great to do the same on the Azure CLI

Answer (score 2):

Direct using Azure CLI publish universial package command to update the version is not supported.

A work around to your demand:

Prepare a local .txt file "C:\temp\File.txt" contains the initial version value "0.0.1".

Use the following PowerShell command to update the version every time.

```
$file = "C:\temp\File.txt"
$fileVersion = [version](Get-Content $file | Select -First 1)
$newVersion = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $fileVersion.Major, $fileVersion.Minor, ($fileVersion.Build + 1)
$newVersion | Set-Content $file
```

[image]

And use the value of newVersion in your Azure CLI command.

Here is the sample:

```
az artifacts universal publish --organization https://dev.azure.com/project/ --project="myProject" --scope project --feed myFeed --name someName --version $newVersion --description "some files" --path .
```

Comment: Kim Xu-MSFT - we are working with several developers, so it is not a practical solution..

Comment: You could also get the Package Version using API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-package-versions?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0. Then modify the version and upload.